# make two tables joint without latexdraw

Tags: tables, join

[image]

may i make this in texmaker without latexdraw? if no why alternate?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The two large frames must have the same height, I suppose?

Comment: already have the answer ?

Comment: yes Master, because i don't know title for my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple tabular with tikz `shapes arrows`  library to draw vertical and horizontal arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\newcommand{\Arrow}[1][0]{\tikz\node [single arrow,draw,shape border uses incircle,
shape border rotate=#1,fill=blue!50,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=1.5cm]{};}
\newcommand{\void}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4cm}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}}



 \begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{|C|M|C|}
 \hline 
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Pengaruh Komunikasi Efectif Terhadap Kinerja Karyawan Pada BMT}    \\
 \hline
 \void                           & \void &  \void                          \\[-6mm]
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Arrow[-90]} & \void &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\Arrow[-90]}\\   
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
 Komunikasi  Efektif (X)         &       & Kinerja Karyawan (Y)            \\
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
 Indicator 
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \end{enumerate}
 &  \Arrow  &
 Indicator 
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \item 
 bla bla bla 
 \end{enumerate}\\
 \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{Fathullah,2007:26} & \void & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Hadari Nawawi,2002:56}
 \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it completely in Tikz, using an `enumerate` list for the lists.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.arrows}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={draw, very thick, font=\sffamily}
}

\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{90,154,215}
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{74,117,157}

\newcommand\bnodes[4][]{%
    \node[anchor=north #2,text width=4.5cm, inner sep=1mm] (#2) at ($(top.south #2)+(0,-2)$) {#3};
    \node[anchor=north #2,text width=4.5cm, inner sep=1mm, minimum height=5cm, label={below:#1}] (b#2) at ($(#2.south #2)+(0,\pgflinewidth)$) {#4};
}

\newcommand\tzarr[2][0]{
    \node[single arrow,  minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=dblue, fill=lblue, shape border rotate=#1] at (#2) {};
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner xsep=5mm, inner ysep=3mm] (top) {Pengaruh Komunikasi Efektif Terhadap Kinerja Karyawan Pada BMT Al-Fatth};

\bnodes[Fathullah, 2007:26]{west}{Komunikasi Efektif (X)}{
    Indikator\\[\baselineskip]
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-1mm, nosep, leftmargin=*]
    \item Pemahaman
    \item Pengaruh kepada sikap
    \item Hubungan yang makin baik
    \item Mampu menyampaikan pesan
    \item Memberikan umpan balik (feedback)
    \item Memperoleh kemampuan berkomunikasi
    \end{enumerate}
}

\bnodes[Hadari Nawawi, 2002:56]{east}{Kinerja Karyawan (Y)}{
    Indikator\\[\baselineskip]
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-1mm, nosep, leftmargin=*]
    \item Tingkat pendidikan
    \item Hasil pekerjaan
    \item Sarana kerja
    \item Keterampilan
    \item Kemampuan menyelesaikan pekerjaan
    \item Tanggung jawab
    \end{enumerate}
}

\tzarr[270]{$(west.north)!.5!(west.north|-top.south)$}
\tzarr[270]{$(east.north)!.5!(east.north|-top.south)$}
\tzarr{$(bwest)!.5!(beast)$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient way of doing it, and it doesn't use tables, but here's my solution, using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\centerline{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw (-4, 0) rectangle (-1,5);
    \draw (4, 0) rectangle (1, 5);
    \draw (-4, 6) rectangle (4, 7);
    \draw[draw=blue,thick,line width=3.0mm,->] (-2.5, 5.9) -- (-2.5,5.1);
    \draw[draw=blue, thick, line width=3.0mm, ->] (2.5,5.9) -- (2.5,5.1);
    \draw[draw=blue, thick,line width=3.0mm, ->] (-.9, 2.5) -- (.9, 2.5);
    \draw (-4, 4.5) -- (-1, 4.5);
    \draw (1, 4.5) -- (4, 4.5);
    \draw (0, 6.5) node {Pengaruh Komunikasi Efektif Terhadap Kinerja 
    Karyawan Pada BMT Al-Fatth};
    \draw (-2.5, 4.7) node {Komunikasi Efektif (X)};
    \draw (-3.5, 4.3) node {Indikator};
    \draw (-3.3,3.7) node {1. Pemahaman};
    \draw (-2.8, 3.3) node {2. Pengaruh pekada sikap};
    \draw (-2.6, 2.9) node {3. Hubungan yang makin baik};
    \draw (-2.5, 2.5) node {4. Mampu menyampaikan pesan};
    \draw (-2.65, 2.1) node {5. Memberikan umpan balik};
    \draw (-3.3, 1.9) node {(feed back)};
    \draw (-2.7, 1.6) node {6. Memperoleh kemampuan};
    \draw (-3, 1.4) node {berkomunikasi};
    %other left box text
    \draw (2.5, 4.7) node {Kinerja Karyawan (Y)};
    \draw (1.5, 4.3) node {Indikator};
    \draw (2.1, 3.7) node {1. Tingkat Pendidikan};
    \draw (1.93, 3.3) node {2. Hasil pekerjaan};
    \draw (1.8, 2.9) node {3. Sarana kerja};
    \draw (1.8, 2.5) node {4. Keterampilan};
    \draw (2.45, 2.1) node {5. Kemampuan menyelesaikan };
    \draw (1.7, 1.9) node {pekerjaan};
    \draw (1.94, 1.5) node {6. Tanggung jawab};
    %other right box text
    \draw (-2.5, -0.5) node {Fathullah, 2007 : 26};
    \draw (2.5, -0.5) node {Hadari Nawawi, 2002: 56};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

(It's hard to tell, but it fills up a decent portion of the page and is properly centered.)

The arrows aren't quite right; I'm working on that. Let me know if there's anything besides the arrows I didn't do right, I'll work on it.

Please note that this was done with sharelatex.com. Hope this helps!

Comment: the numbers aren't all indented the same amount from the left border.  in the box on the right, all items are indented slightly.  in the box on the left, all but number 5 are flush against the border.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you. I noticed that when I was writing the code...it's weird, because it didn't line up properly when I put in the same x-values for each entry. I'll work on it.

Comment: I using ~ for same